# What's the difference between a sigma-algebra on a set and a powerset?

Tags: measure-theory

According to wikipedia, If X = {a, b, c, d}, one possible σ-algebra on X is Σ = { ∅, {a, b}, {c, d}, {a, b, c, d} }, where ∅ is the empty set. In general, a finite algebra is always a σ-algebra.

According to wikipedia, One possible-sigma algebra on X appears to be a powerset of X without the element $\{$ a,b,c $\}$.

How many elements does any sigma-algebra have?

Comment: "How many elements does any sigma-algebra have?" Well, that depends on the sigma algebra

Comment: The powerset always has $2^n$ elements, does the sigma-algebra always have a predictable number of elements? Is the number of elements of a sigma-algebra bounded?

Comment: no, different $\Sigma$-algebras have different numbers of elements

Comment: @brittany There is no such thing as _the_ sigma-algebra on a given set. For any given set, there are _many_ possible choices of sigma-algebra.

Comment: A sigma algebra is a subset of the powerset which satisfies a few special properties which you should have available in your textbook or on the cited wiki page.  The powerset itself is an example of one such subset, but there are many more, for example $\{\emptyset, X\}$ is another.  The number of elements can range anywhere from $2$ to $2^n$ (*or $1$ in the case of the sigma algebra on the emptyset itself... which is generally ignored as it is uninteresting to begin with*).  You can however prove that any sigma-algebra (*apart from the one on $\emptyset$*) will have an even number of elements

Comment: I will point out, that the specific sigma-algebra cited on the wiki page is *not* just the powerset without $\{a,b,c\}$, it is missing *all* of the singleton sets and *all* of the triples.  Further, your copying of it into your question you are missing $\{a,b,c,d\}$ itself in your sigma-algebra, though it must have been included for it to satisfy all of the needed properties.

Comment: That is worth a separate question of its own, but the quick answer is that it is always helpful regardless your level of education, either as a refresher for topics you studied long ago or as a tool for studying new topics that you are just now introducing yourself to.

Comment: @JMoravitz Why is $\{$ a,b $\}$ an element of a sigma-algebra on $\{$ a,b,c,d $\}$? Is the complement of  $\{$ a,b $\}$ equal to $\{$ c,d $\}$, so  $\{$ a,b $\}$ is a element of a sigma-algebra of $\{$ a,b,c,d $\}$?

Comment: Its not that $\{a,b\}$ must be an element of any sigma-algebra on $\{a,b,c,d\}$ (*its not, as already mentioned, an element of the sigma algebra $\{\emptyset,\{a,b,c,d\}\}$*)., but since $\{a,b\}$ *is* an element of **this** sigma-algebra, so too must $\{c,d\}$ be (*because $\{c,d\}=X\setminus\{a,b\}$*), and similarly since $\{c,d\}$ *is* an element of this sigma-algebra, so too must $\{a,b\}$.

Comment: Another example of a sigma-algebra on $\{a,b,c,d\}$ would be $\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b,c,d\},\{a,b,c,d\}\}$, notice again that $\{a,b\}$ is not an element of that sigma-algebra either.  As for *why* $\{a,b\}$ is an element of the sigma-algebra you listed in the first place, it was simply the author's choice and for no other deeper reason than that and that the author knew that particular set satisfied all the necessary properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that any $\sigma$-algebra over some universe $U$ is a family of sets from the power set $\mathcal{P}(U)$ that satisfies the closure conditions of the definition of a $\sigma$-algebra. An example showing that a $\sigma$-algebra need not be the full power set is the trivial $\sigma$-algebra $\{ \emptyset, U \}$.